# Mutable and Immutable Objects

Tags: python, string, immutability

I am trying to get my head around on mutable and immutable objects. I have read that string is immutable and that for each string, a separate object is created with a different object ID. I am trying to verify this using below simple code, however, I see same object ID for multiple strings which are not same. Can someone please clarify this. Thanks in advance.

```
mystring = ""
mylist = ["This ", "That ", "This ", "That ", "This ", "That ", "This ", "That "]

for item in mylist:
    mystring = mystring + item
    print("mystring: ", mystring, "ID of mystring: ", id(mystring))
```

which results in below output:

```
mystring:  This  ID of mystring:  6407264
mystring:  This That  ID of mystring:  42523448
mystring:  This That This  ID of mystring:  42523448
mystring:  This That This That  ID of mystring:  6417200
mystring:  This That This That This  ID of mystring:  42785608
mystring:  This That This That This That  ID of mystring:  42785608
mystring:  This That This That This That This  ID of mystring:  42837536
mystring:  This That This That This That This That  ID of mystring:  42775856
```

Comment: `id`s are reclaimed when not used, so not surprising you are seeing the same `id` because you are discarding the old strings.

Comment: @AChampion: Except that the lifetimes really *should* be overlapping, so ID reuse should be invalid. There's an optimization going on here that doesn't quite preserve the language's guarantees about `id` return values and string immutability.

Comment: @user2357112  the lifetimes are not overlapping.

Comment: @wim: Between the computation of `mystring + item` and the assignment to `mystring`, the lifetimes of successive `mystring` values should overlap. Lifetime overlap isn't transitive, but that doesn't matter, because we're seeing ID reuse for successive `mystring` values. If it weren't for the in-place optimization of `mystring = mystring + item`, this ID reuse wouldn't happen.

Comment: It is precisely the fact that there is no overlap here that makes the in-place optimization a possibility. The time when the name `mystring` is re-bound is the same instant the old `mystring` ceases to have a reference.  Keep another reference to the old and you won't see the optimization anymore!

Comment: @wim: Without the optimization, the new `mystring` value would come into existence before the name binding operation, and then the name binding would end the lifetime of the old `mystring` value. There would be a llifetime overlap between the `+` and the `=`.

Comment: @user2357112 While it's true that there is this optimization and there is an overlap, it is way out of the scope of both the question and the skill-level of the question.

Comment: @user2357112  OK, I see what you are getting at now. There is no overlap - but in a hypothetical world without this optimization, there would be some overlap.

Answer (score 3):

Python is allowed to reuse object IDs for objects with non-overlapping lifetimes, but you're seeing ID reuse in cases where there should be a lifetime overlap. Specifically, during execution of this statement:

```
mystring = mystring + item
```

between the evaluation of `mystring + item` and the assignment to `mystring`, there should be a lifetime overlap between any two successive values of `mystring`. You're seeing ID reuse for successive values of `mystring`, which shouldn't happen.

The effect you're seeing happens because of an optimization in the CPython bytecode evaluation loop, where statements of the form

```
string1 = string1 + string2
```

or

```
string1 += string2
```

are detected, and if the interpreter can confirm that `string1` has no other references, it attempts to perform the concatenation by mutating `string1` in-place. You can see the code in [`Python/ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/ceval.c) under [`unicode_concatenate`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/ceval.c#L5406). This optimization is mostly invisible, due to the refcount check, but the effect on `id` values is one way it's visible.

Answer (score 2):

String *are* immutable. There exist no `str` method that allows to mutate them.

That being said, the reason you see the same id multiple times is because when an object is no longer in use, Python will reuse its position in memory. And what `id` does is precisely to provide a unique identifier by returning the position of the object in memory.

One way to convince yourself that this is indeed the reason for your observation would be to make sure to always have a reference to each of the string you create by adding them to a `list`.

### Code

```
mystring = ""
mylist = ["This ", "That ", "This ", "That ", "This ", "That ", "This ", "That "]

# A list to keep a reference to each string
created_strings = []

for item in mylist:
    mystring = mystring + item

    # Prevent mystring from being garbage collected by adding it to the list
    created_strings.append(mystring)

    print("mystring: ", mystring, "ID of mystring: ", id(mystring))
```

### Output

```
mystring:  This  ID of mystring:  2522900655888
mystring:  This That  ID of mystring:  2522903930416
mystring:  This That This  ID of mystring:  2522903930544
mystring:  This That This That  ID of mystring:  2522902118880
mystring:  This That This That This  ID of mystring:  2522900546624
mystring:  This That This That This That  ID of mystring:  2522900546864
mystring:  This That This That This That This  ID of mystring:  2522902428376
mystring:  This That This That This That This That  ID of mystring:  2522900907952
```

Notice that now that memory is not reclaimed, each object has a different `id`.